# panel's setTitle() function does not publish to the panel's viewModel

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I call the `setTitle` function of extjs panel component, the title update immediately, but the viewModel bind to the it does not change!.

Code is as below :

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {


        var textfield = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            itemId: 'textfieldItem',
            fieldLabel: 'fjdks',
            bind: '{customer.name}'
        });

        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            viewModel: {},
            bind: {
                title: '{customer.name}'
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [textfield]

        });

        panel.setTitle('123');
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', panel.getViewModel().get('customer.name'), function() {
            textfield.setValue('rrrrr');
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', panel.getViewModel().get('customer.name'));
        });

    }
});
```

See [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ga3)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a two-way binding apparently. You can report it to Sencha as a bug or as a missing feature, however, it is pretty easy to fix it by extending Ext.panel.Panel and implementing `applyTitle` method that would publish to viewmodel. If you decide for this approach do not forget to call parent applyTitle.

Comment: It's not a bug, properties aren't 2 way bindable by default. It doesn't really make sense for the title to be 2 wayable because it's not user-settable.

Comment: To floor 1: Do you mean override setTitle function?

Comment: Any farther solution and detail ?